# Wrapping Microsoft's "W" and "A" functions

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm writing a template function which uses notorious Microsoft's `A` and `W` functions. Template argument type is limited to `std::string` and `std::wstring`, therefore I use `struct` wrapper to call required function:

```
template<typename type>
struct formatMessageT;

template<>
struct formatMessageT<std::string> {
    static inline size_t call(DWORD dwFlags, LPCVOID lpSource, DWORD dwMessageId, DWORD dwLanguageId, LPSTR lpBuffer, DWORD nSize, va_list *Arguments) {
        return FormatMessageA(dwFlags, lpSource, dwMessageId, dwLanguageId, lpBuffer, nSize, Arguments);
    }
};

template<>
struct formatMessageT<std::wstring> {
    static inline size_t call(DWORD dwFlags, LPCVOID lpSource, DWORD dwMessageId, DWORD dwLanguageId, LPWSTR lpBuffer, DWORD nSize, va_list *Arguments) {
        return FormatMessageW(dwFlags, lpSource, dwMessageId, dwLanguageId, lpBuffer, nSize, Arguments);
    }
};
```

This, however, is a pain in... Is there a better way to achieve this? I tried to use function template, as seen below:

```
#include <iostream>

char funW(wchar_t) {
    return 'W';
}

char funA(char) {
    return 'A';
}

template<typename returnType, typename function, typename ...Args>
returnType functionCall(function f, Args ...args) {
    return f(args...);
}

int main() {
    bool dummy = true;
    std::cout << functionCall<char>(dummy ? funW : funA, dummy ? L'W' : 'A') << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately this only works when function arguments types match (given that argument itself also matches):

```
char funW(char) {
    return 'W';
}

char funA(char) {
    return 'A';
}
```

or

```
char funW(wchar_t) {
    return 'W';
}

char funA(wchar_t) {
    return 'A';
}
```

Comment: You'll need to use the preprocessor if you want to eliminate the repetition of appending the `A`/`W` to the function names to generate the appropriate dispatching. There's no C++ construct that can generate that for you.

Comment: do you really need it ? compile you app as unicode and use `std::wstring` as your string type

Comment: Easier way is to forget the `A` suffix exists and only use the `W` versions when dealing with the WINAPI.

Comment: There are only few places I'll need this (for debugging purposes), however some workaround would make my job easier

Comment: Templates seem like overkill for this.  Why not define FormatMessageT as two overloaded functions, one that takes `char` strings and one that takes `WCHAR` strings?

Comment: Best guess is that I was working with templates for hours and forgot how to function normally. Better question is why Microsoft didn't do it?

Comment: @Helix because the windows API is a set of DLLs to be linked at runtime and C++ sucks at this with its name mangling, thus all API functions are `extern "C"`-ed. Microsoft's solution for the simple usecase (`#include <Windows.h>`) are makros i.e. `#define FormatMessage FormatMessageW` if `_UNICODE` is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A person who deleted his answer posted solution which did not work for Microsoft's compiler, however after tinkering around the code I managed to adapt it and make it work. Big thanks to you (W.F or someone similar)!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <bool, class T1, class T2, T1, T2>
struct nontype_conditional;

template <class T1, class T2, T1 Foo1, T2 Foo2>
struct nontype_conditional<true, T1, T2, Foo1, Foo2> {
    template<typename ...Args>
    static auto run(Args&&... args) {
        return Foo1(std::forward<decltype(args) && >(args)...);
    }
};

template <class T1, class T2, T1 Foo1, T2 Foo2>
struct nontype_conditional<false, T1, T2, Foo1, Foo2> {
    template<typename ...Args>
    static auto run(Args&&... args) {
        return Foo2(std::forward<decltype(args) && >(args)...);
    }
};

char funW(char) {
    return 'W';
}

char funA(wchar_t) {
    return 'A';
}

constexpr bool value = true;

int main() {
    std::cout << nontype_conditional<value, decltype(funW)&, decltype(funA)&, funW, funA>::run(value ? 'a' : L'a') << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```